# Разделитель в путях

Tags: windows, терминология

Есть путь, пусть такой: `C:\papka`. Существует ли какое-нибудь название знака "\", входящего в него?

Comment: Обратная косая черта, обратный слэш... *Google* много знает, почему бы сачала у него не спросить?

Comment: Не знал, как спросить. Вопрос "Как называется обратный слэш?" кажется мне достаточно каламбурным. Термин *обратный слэш* встречал только в литературе по LaTeX, так что думал, что такое название характерно для этого языка программирования, хотя, честно говоря, по другим языкам листал не так и много книг.

Comment: А, стоп. Я имел ввиду как называется слэш не сам по себе, а именно его название в контексте вхождения его в путь. Вот существует ли какое-нибудь название как разделителя его составляющих частей путя?

Comment: Так и называется: **разделитель**, либо знак пунктуации.

Answer (score 1):

"***Методическое руководство для преподавателей информатики, основ вычислительной техники и компьютерной грамотности, МинПрос, 2003 г.***" С тех пор вроде бы не переиздавалось, но даже если и так, вряд ли что-то поменялось.

Цитата из методички:

"<...> рекомендуется избегать жаргонизмов в назывании спец.символов. Рекомендуемые названия <...> приведены в Глоссарии, страницы 87-96."

Идём в глоссарий:

**"\" - "обратная дробная черта", допускается также термин "обратная косая черта"**

В конце глоссария указаны ГОСТы, по которым он составлен: 16330-85, 14289-88, 34.302.2-91. Любопытства ради сейчас просмотрел один - да, действительно :)

Длинно и, что уж говорить, - неудобно, в профессиональных разговорах я редко слышу, как кто-то так говорит, обычно - "бэкслэш". Хотя от фортранистов иногда слышу "ОКЧ" и "ПЧ" :)

Но когда читаю лекции, неважно, для какой аудитории, или провожу семинары, стараюсь следовать рекомендациям и избегать использования арго. Впрочем, сам употребляю при этом термин "обратная косая черта".